# Slowness in creating object bricks

Tags: mysql, pimcore

Pimcore v 3.1.1

We have set up an automated process to periodically update a number of object bricks definitions.

We do it using Object_Objectbrick_Definition() class.

We noticed that the creation time is not constant on a system currently not loaded with other requests. It varies from less than 30 seconds to more than 4 minutes. It seems not dependant to the complexity of the object brick (number of components,...).
There are no objects that currently use the object bricks but the object bricks are associated to 2 class definition

Is there something to check about this slowness?

During object brick creation/update we see several errors that seems to have no effect. They may be related to the slowness? How we can avoid them?

Errors are like these:

```
2016-02-16T18:59:28+01:00 ERR (3): 242 MB | Pimcore\Resource\Mysql::errorHandler() [312]: 
[Exception] with message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
1091 Can't DROP 'p_index_<class-datacomponent>'; check that column/key exists, query was: ALTER TABLE `object_store_<class-id>` DROP INDEX `p_index_<class-datacomponent>`;

2016-02-16T18:59:28+01:00 ERR (3): 242 MB | Pimcore\Resource\Mysql::errorHandler() [312]: 
[Exception] with message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
1061 Duplicate key name 'p_index_<class-datacomponent>', query was: ALTER TABLE `object_query_<class-id>` ADD INDEX `p_index_<class-datacomponent>` (`<class-datacomponent>`);
```

Comment: Which version of Pimcore You're using? Also, could You provide a code that updates the number of object bricks definitions?

My first guess is that mysql indexes are being rebuilt during those operations - this can take a long time.

Comment: @kubaplas : (version 3.1.1) I think your first guess is the right one. I'll search how to and try to disable mysql reindexing... do you know already know how to do it? My idea is to disable it at the start of the periodic update and re-enable at the end.

Comment: I think You should check Your code for inserts and updates into indexed columns and try to refactor it to minimise those.